# How I make my Jupyter notebook script locked?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

I have multiple scripts using the IRkernel on Jupyter notebook. I have to put them on a server, but I only want that people can run it, not editable or deletable.
I have already tried things, mainly by modifying the metadatas like that :

```
{
  "deletable": false,
  "editable": false,
  "trusted": true
}
```

But when it would be on the server, others people can modify the metadatas, so it is not really what I want.
Is there a way to make my script fully locked and that nobody can editable it ?

Comment: Make the metadata write protected too.

Comment: Thanks it would be great, but I don't succeed to do that. Can you give me an exemple about how to do it please ?

Comment: Find the real file _(probably your entire script)_ on your server and make it write protected using your filesystem's file attributes. (example for Linux ext4: `sudo chattr +i FILENAME`) Please excuse me, should my answer be off-topic.

Comment: What I meant is that I want to lock the script to make it not editable, I want people can only run it without modifications. I tried your proposition but it doesn't do it